# Prevent Concurrent Modification. Eclipselink (OptimisticLockException)

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, optimistic-locking

Problem:

Two Admins -> Admin1 and Admin2 Simultaneously modifying UserA from different terminals.

There is a **many-to-many** relation between User and UserGroup entity.

Here what is happening is when Admin1 assigns Group1 to UserA, the information is saved.
And when Admin2 from different terminal assigns Group2 to UserA, the information saved but overwrites the changes made by Admin1. Means when I check in DB, UserA is assigned to Group2 while Admin2 is not aware of changes made by Admin1.

1. Is this Optimistic Situation?
2. If this is optimistic situation then why this is not throwing OptimisticLockException?
3. How would I notify Admin2 about the changes made by Admin1.

Using Eclipselink as below:

```
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_group", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<User> userList;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_group",joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_group_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private List<UserGroup> userGroupList;
```

@Version annotation is marked over version column which is updated on each operation.

Let know if you require more information from my side.

Answer (score 0):

When group1 is assigned to user1, save last modified timestamp. Next time when the request comes to get the user1 details make sure you provide last modified date along with other details.  When admin1 modifies the request ask him to provide the same last modified date which you supplied during get operation. Compare the last modified date  s same as what you provided to admin1 before saving the requestrequest. Basically here last modified date is kind of token. You store a token, provide the same to user accessing the data and then when user modifies the data and sends it for persist operation make sure token in the database matches the one user has sent back to you else it means that the record was modifed and the token is changed in databse and dont allow the user to persist bad data.

Hope this helps.